# Error: Package array Error: Illegal pream-toke ([): `c` used

Tags: tables, siunitx

Why I have this error?

[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering 
\begin{tabular*}{0.80\textwidth}{
  @{}
  l
  c[table-format=6]
  c[table-format=6]
  c[table-format=6]
  c[table-format=6]
  @{}  
}
\toprule
{\thead{Sample Setting \\ Configuration}} 
  & {\thead{Verification \\ 
  Status}}
  & {\thead{Precision \\ (\textit{P})}}
  & {\thead{Recall \\ (\textit{R}) }}
  & {\thead{\textit{F}-samples }} \\
\midrule

No. 4   &   66.07   &   0.6786  &   0.6552  &   0.6667  \\
No. 5   &   71.43   &   0.7097  &   0.7586  &   0.7333  \\


\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Replace "c" with "S". Also, adapt the numbers according to the table content. For the second column, use  2.2  instead of 6, for the third c use, 1.4.

Comment: LaTeX's basic `l`, `c` and `r` column types do *not* take arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `c` type column does not accept an optional argument, hence the error message you get. In order to make your code compilable, replace `c` with `S`. The latter is a column type defined by the `siunitx` package, which, among others accepts the `table-format` option that you used. In order to get the correct alignment of the numbers, as well as the right column widths, you should also correct the values of `table-format` according to the contents of the corresponding table columns. In the following example, I have also added `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` in order to make sure the table is as wide as the specified width, while the columns are spread evenly:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering 
\begin{tabular*}{0.80\textwidth}{
  @{}
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  @{}  
}
\toprule
{\thead{Sample Setting \\ Configuration}} 
  & {\thead{Verification \\ 
  Status}}
  & {\thead{Precision \\ (\textit{P})}}
  & {\thead{Recall \\ (\textit{R}) }}
  & {\thead{\textit{F}-samples }} \\
\midrule

No. 4   &   66.07   &   0.6786  &   0.6552  &   0.6667  \\
No. 5   &   71.43   &   0.7097  &   0.7586  &   0.7333  \\


\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```